# splashscreen is not visible in netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans

[enter link description here][1]I tried an application to display a GIF file. But my application is not showing any error instead GIf ( splash screen ) is not visible.

I have given a code in manifest file :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
```

X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build `SplashScreen-Image:C:\Users\Admin\Documents\NetBeansProjects\splash\src\splash\try5.gif`

```
-splash:src\splash\try5.gif
```

the above code in VM options.

In my main class i used this code

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
 sleepThread();
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
             new welcome().setVisible(true);
         }

         });
}
private static void sleepThread() {
    try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            // Do something, if there is a exception
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } 
}

    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

But when i tried running my application it doesnot display my Splashscreen. Is there any specification for the size of the Splashscreen GIf because my file is 2.63 MB and its dimensions are 640 * 360. Kindly help me.

EDIT : I USED THE SAME CODING BUT TRIED A JPG IMAGE AS A SPLASH SCREEN IT WORKED WELL. THEN AGAIN I CHANGED IT TO .GIF FILE THE SPLASH SCREEN DID NOT APPEAR AND ALSO AGAIN I CHANGED MY FILE WITH JPG FILE THIS TIME THIS JPG FILE ALSO DID NOT WORK.

EDIT : [1]: http://giphy.com/gifs/thank-you-cute-a3IWyhkEC0p32

Here is the link i have given for a sample gif file. But please note that my gif file size is 2.53 MB.

EDIT : Now this Gif file works perfectly. But after dis splash screen stops my Jframe should open. how do i map it so dat it if i run my program it First displays my Splashscreen den my Frame.

Comment: no need to do anything with your manifest.

Comment: No I did not get the solution as I am not able to display the splash screen

Comment: The file size / dimension does not matter. It is an image. Just make sure your frame size is as big as your image, so it does not clip the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops!

I didn't notice. It is better to use SwingUtilities for forms and swing objects to work with. // Change the sleep to 5000, it is 2000 now.

```
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final JDialog frame = new JDialog(new JFrame());
        frame.setSize(320, 240);
        frame.setContentPane(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("H:\\walk.gif")));
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                sleepThread();
                CloseDialog(frame);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }).start();

        ShowDialog(frame);

    }

    private static void sleepThread() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // Do something, if there is a exception
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    private static void ShowDialog(final JDialog dialog) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private static void CloseDialog(final JDialog dialog) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                dialog.setVisible(false);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry sir but dis also displays jframe only and not the gif splash screen

Comment: Did you add the gif image to your frame?

Comment: I am getting error in JLabel. I have given the code in my main class.

Comment: Now this Gif file works perfectly. But after dis stops my Jframe should open. how do i map it so dat it if i run my program it First displays my Splashscreen den my Frame.

Comment: You can do whatever you want within CloseDialog() method. After closing the splash, you can view your main form. My suggestion is that create a new method like ShowDialog() and call it via SwingUtilities.invokeLater().

Answer (score 0):

swap commands, and you will be fine. Show the window, then sleep. That is how splash screen work, I think :)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
new welcome().setVisible(true); 
 java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run()
         {
              sleepThread();
         }

         });
}
private static void sleepThread() {
    try
        {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex)
        {
            // Do something, if there is a exception
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        } 
}

    // TODO code application logic here
}
```

Comment: no this opened two frames but did not display splash screen